# Delete all files with *.zip except latest 5(recent) files under windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have filenames called

```
abc_1.zip
abc_2.zip
abc_3.zip
abc_4.zip
abc_5.zip(below_latest)
abc_6.zip(latest)
```

under windows server 2012 r2. Now I need a single command to delete all files except the latest and below_latest one.

Note: The above names are just for example. So I can say I want to keep the only recent file(latest and below_latest) and remove all.

Also, I need a single line command, not a PowerShell script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single Line PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -file | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Remove-Item
```

or using some aliases:

```
ls -file | sort LastWriteTime -d | Select -Skip 2 | rm
```

if you are not in the directory with the files to delete use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test ...
```